# Material UI snackbars not working properly in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, snackbar

I am trying to use Material UI components in NextJS but they are not working properly.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// MATERIAL
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";
import MuiAlert from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";

export default class NewProduct extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      testSnack: false,
    };
  }

 testSnackbars = () => {
    this.setState({ testSnack: true });
 };

  render(){
     return{
       <>
       <Snackbar
      open={this.state.testSnack}
      autoHideDuration={5000}
      onClose={this.handleClose}
    >
      <MuiAlert
        elevation={6}
        variant="filled"
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        severity="success"
      >
        Product Added!
      </MuiAlert>
    </Snackbar>

      <button onClick={this.testSnackbars}>
        Save
      </button>
    </>
    }
  }
}
```

This is a simple logic for showing snackbar on button click but this doesnt seem to work in NextJs, I use Material in ReactJs very often and this never happened there. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I am not able to run snackbars using my state. If I pass in open={true} property, it shows up but not working through state variable.

Comment: And if you click the button you don't receive any error?

Comment: A sandbox would be helpful

Comment: No errors on button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
return {...};
```

with

```
return (...);
```

Besides that, everything seems to look good on my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-clarke-w08jt?file=/src/NewProduct.tsx).

Comment: It is (...) only. Typing mustake

Comment: Add the problematic code to codesandbox, there is a NextJs template. It will be faster for us to track down the problem this way.